# Grunt Serve - express:dev task gets stuck

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs

I'm having issues with my grunt serve task. It seems to hang when it gets to the express:dev task;

**Running "express:dev" (express) task**
Starting background Express server
Debugger listening on port 5858

This an existing project where grunt serve used to work fine. This issue started yesterday when my Mac ran out of power mid process; in my head its either that or I have inadvertently changed something and broken it just before the mac went down and the power thing is just coincidence.

Has anyone got any ideas?

```
'use strict';


module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);


    var deploySettings = grunt.file.readJSON('config.json'),
    deploy = deploySettings.production;
    var useminSettings = []


    var appConfig = {
        app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
        dist: 'dist' //require('./bower.json').distPath || 
    };

    grunt.initConfig({

        mainApp: appConfig,

        express: {
          options: {
            port: process.env.PORT || 9000
        },
        dev: {
            options: {
                script: 'app.js',
                debug: true,
                node_env: 'development',
                livereload:true,
                serverreload: true
            }
        },
        prod: {
            options: {
                script: 'dist/app.js',
                node_env: 'production'
            }
        }
    },

    watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['wiredep']
        },
        js : {

            files: ['<%= mainApp.app %>/js/**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
            options: {
                    livereload: true //'<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                }

            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            less: {
                files: ['<%= mainApp.app %>/css/**/*.less'],
                tasks: ['less:development']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload : true //'<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                '<%= mainApp.app %>/**/*.html',
            '<%= mainApp.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        },
        express: {
            files: [
            'server/**/*.{js,json}'
            ],
            tasks: ['less:development','express:dev', 'wait'],
            options: {
              livereload: true,
                  nospawn: true //Without this option specified express won't be reloaded
              }
          }
      },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        /*
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: '0.0.0.0',
                livereload: 35729
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect().use(
                                '/bower_components',
                                connect.static('./bower_components')
                            ),
                            connect.static(appConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        */


        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        wiredep: {
            app: {
                src: ['<%= mainApp.app %>/index.html']
                //ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
            }
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: {
                src: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= mainApp.app %>/js/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        }
    },

        //compiles our less down
        less : {
            development:{
                options:{
                    path: '<%= mainApp.app %>/css/main.less',
                    rootPath: '/css/',
                    relativeUrls: false
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= mainApp.app %>/css/main.css' : '<%= mainApp.app %>/css/main.less'
                }
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
              files: [{
                  dot: true,
                  src : [
                  '.tmp',
              '<%= mainApp.dist %>/{,*/}*',
              '<%= mainApp.dist %>/.git*'
              ]
          }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
  },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= mainApp.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= mainApp.dist %>/public',
                flow: {
                    html: {
                        steps: {
                            js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                            css: ['cssmin']
                        },
                        post: {}
                    }
                }

            }
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '<%= mainApp.dist %>/public/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },

        // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
        // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
        ngAnnotate: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                    src: ['*.js'],
                    dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
                }]
            }
        },

        //copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= mainApp.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= mainApp.dist %>/public',
                    src:[
                    '*.html',
                'views/partials/{,*/}*.html',
            'static/img/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,ico,svg}',
        'css/fonts/{,*/}*.{ttf,woff,eot,otf}'
        ]
    }, {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '.tmp/images',
        dest: '<%= mainApp.dist %>/public/images',
        src: ['generated/*']
    }, {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
    src: 'fonts/{,*/}*.{ttf,woff,eot,otf}',
    dest: '<%= mainApp.dist %>/public'
}, {
    expand: true,
    dest: '<%= mainApp.dist %>',
    src: [
    'app.js',
    'package.json',
    'server/**/*'
    ]
}]
},
debug: {
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: '<%= mainApp.app %>',
        dest: '<%= mainApp.dist %>',
        src:[
        '*.html',
    'views/partials/{,*/}*.html',
'js/{,*/}*.js',
'css/{,*/}*.css',
'static/img/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
'css/fonts/{,*/}*.{ttf,woff,eot,otf}'
]
}, {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '.tmp/images',
    dest: '<%= mainApp.dist %>/images',
    src: ['generated/*']
}, {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
src: 'fonts/{,*/}*.{ttf,woff,eot,otf}',
dest: '<%= mainApp.dist %>'
}]
},
styles : {
  expand: true,
  cwd: '<%= mainApp.app %>/styles',
  dest: '.tmp/styles',
src: '{,*/}*.css'
}
},

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
        concurrent: {
          dist:[
          'copy:styles'
          ]

      },

        // Replace Google CDN references
        cdnify: {
            dist: {
                html: ['<%= mainApp.dist %>/public/*.html']
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        filerev: {
            dist: {
                src: [
            '<%= mainApp.dist %>/public/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= mainApp.dist %>/public/styles/{,*/}*.css'
//          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
//          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
]
}
},

        // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
        html: ['<%= mainApp.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.html'],
    css: ['<%= mainApp.dist %>/public/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
    options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= mainApp.dist %>/public']
    }
},


htmlmin: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            conservativeCollapse: true,
            collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
            removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
            removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= mainApp.dist %>',
        src: ['*.html', 'views/partials{,*/}*.html'],
        dest: '<%= mainApp.dist %>/public'
    }]
}
},

imagemin : {
            dynamic: {                         // Another target
                files: [{
                    expand: true,                  // Enable dynamic expansion
                    cwd: '<%= mainApp.dist %>/public/static',  // Src matches are relative to this path
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],   // Actual patterns to match
                    dest: '<%= mainApp.dist %>/public/static'                  // Destination path prefix
                }]
            }

        },


});



    // Used for delaying livereload until after server has restarted
    grunt.registerTask('wait', function () {
        grunt.log.ok('Waiting for server reload...');

        var done = this.async();

        setTimeout(function () {
          grunt.log.writeln('Done waiting!');
          done();
      }, 1500);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('express-keepalive', 'Keep grunt running', function() {
        this.async();
    });



    grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function(){



     grunt.task.run([
         'clean:server',
         'less:development',
         'wiredep',
          // 'concurrent:server',
           //'connect:livereload',
           'express:dev',
           //'express-keepalive',
           'wait',
           'watch'

           ]);

 });



    grunt.registerTask('build', function(){

            grunt.task.run([
                'clean:dist',
                'less:development',
                'wiredep',
                'useminPrepare',
                'concurrent:dist',
                'copy:styles',
                'autoprefixer',
                'concat',
                'ngAnnotate',
                'copy:dist',
                'cdnify',
                'cssmin',
                'uglify',
                'filerev',
                'usemin',
                'htmlmin',
                'express:dev'
                ]);

    });




grunt.registerTask('debug', [
    'clean:dist',
    'less:development',
    'wiredep',
    'copy:debug'
    ]);






grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'serve'
    ]);


};
```

Comment: Post the Gruntfile to give more information.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this by reverting to a previous git and manually adding changed.

Somehow it was an issue with node-scheduler. I was scheduling a task using a recurrence rule for dayOfWeek = 7. This was producing the error in grunt serve, nothing to do with the grunt file as it happens.

I changed this to dayOfWeek = 0 and it was fine.